# Format for int since XCode 4.5

Tags: ios, xcode, string-formatting, lldb

Since upgrading to XCode 4.5, printing `ints` to the console results in unusually high values. Eg:

```
int someInt = 300;
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some int: %d", someInt]); // prints Some int: 11581443
```

Usually I only see this when using the wrong format string for the data type. I'm using LLDB.

Comment: Please provide an exact, specific instance of code that is exhibiting this behavior. (The code you provided doesn't compile since it's missing a colon in `stringWithFormat:`. After fixing that, the code works just fine here in a fresh project).

Answer (score 3):

you wrong use `NSLog`.

```
void NSLog (
   NSString *format,
   ...
);
```

ex:

```
int someInt = 100;
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",someInt];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

or

```
NSLog(@"%d", someInt)
```

or

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",someInt])
```

Comment: But there must be something else. `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some int: %d", someInt]` evaluates to "Some int: 300", so we have `NSlog(@"Some int: 300")`, and that string does not contain any format specifier. So even if you should not use it like that, it does not explain the OP's problem.

Comment: As @MartinR said, while the OP's usage of `NSLog()` may be considered potentially insecure, in this specific case it makes no difference...

Answer (score 1):

Try `NSLog(@"Integer: %i", int)`

Comment: `%d` and `%i` are basically synonymous; shouldn't make a difference. Something else has to be at play....

Comment: @NSGod `Try NSLog(@"Integer: %d", int)` also true

Answer (score 0):

@askovpen is right about your incorrect use of `NSLog`, however this line in your question is interesting :

> using the wrong format string for the data type

Of course you get garbage out - you're putting garbage in!

`NSLog` works by using the first parameter to work out how big the other parameters are going to be. i.e. if you put `%c` it expects a char next in the parameters. If you put `%d` it expects an int. So if you pass in an int and tell it to expect a float then yea, it's not going to work. Why would you expect that it would?

The reason you might be getting different values in XCode 4.5 instead of other XCodes might be due to changes in the memory management during compilation, or might be due to any number of other things.